# Mostrar divs que contienen la misma palabra

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber cómo activar una caja según palabras buscada, digamos que busco la palabra **Primera** me activará la caja 1 que es la que contiene esa palabra, y si busco la palabra **caja** me mostrará todas las cajas, ya que todas contienen esa palabra

¿cómo puedo lograr esto? usando simplemente javascript, y sin realizar busqueda de clases, ya que al realizar una busqueda de clases mostrarán un resultado muy limitado en texto.

```css
.box{
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<input id="" type="text" placeholder="Palabra...">
<button>Mostrar</button>

<div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la primera caja</div>

<div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la segunda caja</div>

<div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la tercera caja</div>

<div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la cuarta caja</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para una solución solo con javascript puedes usar `document.getElementsByClassName()` para obtener todas las cajas, e `indexOf()` para saber si contienen dichos elementos:

```js
function mostrar () {
    var im = document.getElementById('imostrar').value;
    var cajas = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    if(im!='')
      for (var i = 0; i < cajas.length; i ++)
        if(cajas[i].textContent.indexOf(im)>-1)
          cajas[i].style.display="block";
        else
          cajas[i].style.display="none";
    else
      for (var i = 0; i < cajas.length; i ++)
        cajas[i].style.display="none";
  }
```

```css
.box{
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Palabra..." id="imostrar">
<button onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar</button>

<div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la primera caja</div>

<div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la segunda caja</div>

<div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la tercera caja</div>

<div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la cuarta caja</div>
```

También debe tomarse en cuenta que al estar el `<input>` vació deben desaparecer las cajas.

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurre que lo hagas del siguiente modo:

- Dado que deseas verificar todos los `divs` para encontrar la coincidencia en 1 o todos, entonces usa `document.getElementsByTagName()` que te devolverá todos los elementos que la posean
- Usa `for of` para iterar los valores
- Usa la propiedad de los `div` que será `innerText` para obtener el texto que existe entre la etiqueta de apertura y cierre
- Usa el método `includes` para verificar si existe el valor que escribas en el `input text`
- Si existe aplicas la propiedad `display: block;` para mostrar el `div` que lo posea

```html
        <style>
          .box{
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: #ddd;
          }
        </style>
        <input id="cajita" type="text" placeholder="Palabra...">
        <button id="btn">Mostrar</button>
        
        <div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la primera caja</div>
        
        <div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la segunda caja</div>
        
        <div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la tercera caja</div>
        
        <div class="box" style="display:none;">Esta es la cuarta caja</div>
        
        <script>
          let divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div")
          let caja = document.getElementById("cajita")
          let btn = document.getElementById("btn")
          
          btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            for(elemento of divs) {
              if(elemento.innerText.includes(caja.value)) {
                  elemento.style.display = "block"
              }
            }
          })
          
          
        </script>
```

Comment: +1 por espíritu deportivo, aunque con `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` obtiene todos los divs de la pagina, podría obtener otros divs que no tengan clase `box`.

Comment: comprendido @the-breaker apuntado para no cometer de nuevo dicho error

Comment: no, no es error, el OP no especifico, pero se debe tomar en cuenta.

Answer (score 3):

Ya te han ofrecido soluciones que resuelven el problema puntual, te dejo aquí una propuesta con un concepto mas escalable, que seŕia definir los textos en un array y que a partir de ahí se haga todo lo demás. Solo cambiando ese array cambia todo lo demás. Además en este caso yo preferiría `.test` en lugar de `.includes` porque nos da mas flexibilidad en la comparación.

```js
const textos = ['Esta es la primera caja', 'Esta es la segunda caja', 'Esta es la tercera caja',
  'Esta es la cuarta caja',
  'Esta es la quinta caja',
  'Esta no es una caja'
];

const divs = textos.map(e => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerText = e;
  div.classList.add("box");
  div.style.display = 'none';
  return div;
});

divs.forEach(d => document.body.append(d));

document.getElementById("palabra").addEventListener("input", () => {

  const texto = document.getElementById("palabra").value;

  textos.forEach((t, i) => {
    const r = new RegExp(texto, "gi");
    divs[i].style.display = (texto && r.test(t)) ? 'block' : 'none';
  });

});
```

```html
<body>
  <input id="palabra" type="text" placeholder="Palabra...">
  <button onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar</button>
</body>
```

En lugar de tomar el click del botón Mostrar, lo puse en el evento input del mismo input, por una cuestión de comodidad en las pruebas.